# Xcode, CMake: установка и подключение assimp dylib, ошибка __abort_with_payload

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, library, project

Используя **CMake** (использовал *Xcode* в роли *genrator*, другие варианты не работали) я собрал **Xcode** проект для библиотеки **assimp 4** на рабочий стол и скомпилировал проект. Затем я подключил полученную библиотеку к своему проекту под Mac OS: добавил `.dylib` в раздел *`Link Binary with Libraries`* и указал путь до заголовочных файлов в *`Header Search Paths`*. И так-то это сработало, мой проект компилировался и загружал модели с помощью этой библиотеки.

**CMake** создал Xcode проект **assimp** размером 223 МБ, хотя размер итогового файла `.dylib` всего лишь 23 МБ, а его заголовков – меньше одного МБ. Также, мне не нужна папка этого проекта **assimp** на рабочем столе. Поэтому я решил переместить библиотеку с её заголовками и удалить прочие файлы.

В своём Xcode проекте под Mac OS я удалил ссылки на `.dylib` **assimp**'а и его заголовки, затем повторил все те же шаги для подключения библиотеки, уже с новыми путями. В итоге, у меня получается собрать проект без ошибок и запустить его, но затем сразу же выскакивает ошибка: `__abort_with_payload`. Я пробовал почистить проект используя `Clean`, а также некоторые другие советы, однако ничего не помогло. Также я пробовал сохранить директорию проекта **assimp** и просто убрать её с рабочего стола, но это всё равно приводит к той же ошибке исполнения.

Как это можно исправить? Надеюсь, существует другой способ, чем банальная перекомпиляция проекта библиотеки, это был довольно удручающий процесс. И почему это происходит? Возможно, `.dylib` хранит пути до других файлов из проекта, где он был создан? Или я просто упустил какой-то шаг для подключения библиотеки?

Версия **Xcode**: 8.3.3.

---

### Решение

Спасибо **@arrowd** за наводку, проект библиотеки нужно было ещё *установить*, чтобы полученные файлы сохранились в системных директориях. Однако таргет `install` в **Xcode** выдаёт ошибку о том, что не может скопировать файлы. Поэтому я собрал проект по-новой (используя генератор *Unix Makefiles*), затем в полученной папке проекта выполнил `make` для сборки проекта и `sudo make install` для установки с правами администратора, чтобы скрипт мог копировать в системные папки. В итоге, заголовочные файлы попали сюда:

```
/usr/local/include/assimp
```

А файл `.dylib` сюда:

```
/usr/local/lib/libassimp.4.0.0.dylib
```

После этого в **Xcode** проекте, где должна использоваться библиотека, нужно сделать следующее:

- В разделе **`Biuld Settings`** нужно добавить

  1. `/usr/local/include/` к **`Header Search Paths`**
  2. `/usr/local/lib/` к **`Library Search Paths`**
- В разделе **`Build Phases`** нужно прикрепить `.dylib` библиотеку к **`Link Binary with Libraries`**.

Однако почему так происходит мы не выяснили; принимаются комментарии на этот счёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите assimp после компиляции. Если с помощью `make` компилировали, то `make install`. Это скопирует все нужные файлы в `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, а после этого директорию, в которой компилировали можно будет удалить.

Comment: Нет, с помощью CMake создал Xcode проект библиотеки, в нём и компилировал. Добавил уточнения в вопрос.

Comment: Ну там все равно должен быть таргет или проект `INSTALL`. Ну или соберите с помощью `Makefiles`.

Comment: Да, таргет такой есть, но выдаёт ошибку: `CMake Error: Error processing file: cmake_install.cmake. make: *** [install_buildpart_0] Error 1. Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2` 
И перед этим вот этом: `PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ PostBuild\ Rules /Users/Aivan/Desktop/assimp_bin-4-xcode/Assimp.build/Debug/install.build/Script-DA87B66964EA4E33AE918450.sh`
    `cd /Users/Aivan/Downloads/assimp-4.0.0`
    `/bin/sh -c /Users/Aivan/Desktop/assimp_bin-4-xcode/Assimp.build/Debug/install.build/Script-DA87B66964EA4E33AE918450.sh`

Comment: Небось, пытается поставить в директорию, в которую нельзя писать. Куда устанавливаете?

Comment: Спасибо за советы, у меня всё получилось, добавил решение в вопрос.

Comment: По-хорошему, надо было не с `sudo` устанавливать, а в другую папку ставить. Себе в `~`, например.

Comment: А где эту целевую директорию можно указать? В скриптах установки? Если что, у меня CMake с GUI.

Comment: Я же написал, это задает переменная `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. Ее можно изменить и в GUI.